# Telegram Bot message character limitation

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Telegram Bot API documentation says that it doesn't count entities in the text, but sometimes it does.

I want to use Telegram limitation to the maximum.

[As this Telegram Bot API documentation says:](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)
*Text of the message to be sent, 1-4096 characters after entities parsing.*

If I read the documentation correctly, entities doesn't count as a character, so I made this method to get the sum of all entities.

```
    private static final Pattern HTML_TAGS = Pattern.compile("<b>|</b>|<i>|</i>|<s>|</s>|<code>|</code>|<u>|</u>|<a href='.*?'>(.*?)</a>");

    private int GetLengthOfFormattingTags(String text) {
        Matcher matcher = HTML_TAGS.matcher(text);
        int tagTotalLength = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                String tag = matcher.group(i);
                if (tag == null) continue; // Дивно, чомусь matcher.group(i) повертає null.

                if (i > 0) {
                    // Гіперпосилання, видаляємо довжину тексту.
                    tagTotalLength -= tag.length();
                } else {
                    // Знайдено HTML тег, додаємо до довжини.
                    tagTotalLength += tag.length();
                }
            }
        }

        return tagTotalLength;
    }
```

Now, to finish my idea I have to use the sum of all entities.

```
    public String ApplyTextLimitation(String text, short characterLimit) {
        // У документації вказано, що форматування не враховується до кінцевої довжени тексту.
        int uselessLength = GetLengthOfFormattingTags(text);
        int _characterLimit = (int) characterLimit + uselessLength;

        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        System.out.println("Text length with no entities: " + (text.length() - uselessLength));

        if (text.length() > _characterLimit) {
            text = text.substring(0, _characterLimit - 3).concat("...");

            //text = RemoveLastUnclosedTag(text);
        }

        return text;
    }
```

[Sending message, and it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ouJ0.png)

[BUT, if I put one more entity to make my 'A' bold and italic I see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpi9D.png)

Where's the problem?